# My while function is not working PYTHON, I dont know what is wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I've created this while loop below but it just prints "hey" once when it should print it twice, please help:

```
count = 6
item = 3

while count - item > 0:
    print count
    count -= item
    print count
    if count == 0:
        print "hey"
```

at the start, count is 6, then it is 3 but it never gets to 0

Comment: count is only 0 once...

Comment: Why did you expect it to print twice?

Comment: Try stepping through this on [PythonTutor's visualizer](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#), or in a debugger, or just by adding more `print` information (say, `print count, item, count - item`), and it should be obvious what's happening. The first time, `6 - 3 > 0` is true. The second time `3 - 3 > 0` is false. That's all there is to it.

Comment: As for how to fix it, that depends on what you're confused about. If, say, you were looking for it to work because `3 - 3 >= 0` is true, that's a trivial typo; you just did `>` instead of `>=`. If it's something else, the fix is something else.

Comment: It does not print `"hey" at all...

Comment: i want the count to get to 0, so that "hey" will be printed twice

Comment: @DavidMeléndez: but it does not print `"hey"` at all, since if `count == 0`, that means that earlir `count == item`, and thus the `while` loop is not triggered at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should it?

Let us analyze the code flow. Initially `count` and `item` are set to:

```
count = 6; item = 3
```

so that means that `count - item` is `3` so we enter the loop. In the loop we update `count` to `3`, so:

```
count = 3; item = 3
```

so this means that you print `count - item` which is `0`, but `count` itself is `3`, so the `if` statement fails, and we do *not* print `"hey"` at all.

Now the `while` loop checks if `count - item > 0` which is no longer the case, so it stops.

A minimal fix to print `"hey"` twice here, is:

1. set the check in the while loop to `count - item >= 0`; and
2. print `"hey"` in the loop, regardless what the value of `count` is, like:

```
count = 6
item = 3

while count - item >= 0:
    count -= item
    print "hey"
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean? `"hey"` should be printed only once.

I think what you meant was

```
count = 6
item = 3

while count > 0:
    count -= item
    print count - item
    if count == 0:
        print "hey"
```

In your situation, it's checking if `count-item` is greater than 0.